# NodeJS MongoDB - how to fix update operation document must contain atomic operators?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new to mongodb and Nodejs, I want to know what is the problem with my code,

I'm encountering update operation document must contain atomic operators when using updateOne,

here is my code,

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://url-this-is-working";


MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbase = db.db("SampleNodeDB"); 
  var myquery = { address: "Valley 345" };
  var newvalues = { name: "Mickey", address: "Canyon 123" };
  dbase.collection("customers").updateOne(myquery, newvalues, function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw erre
    console.log("1 document updated");
    db.close();
  });
});
```

can someone help me identify and correct the problem,

thankyou!

Comment: `var dbase = db.db("SampleNodeDB"); ` here is error

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You try to update to new values with the query

```
    var newvalues = { name: "Mickey", address: "Canyon 123" };
```

but you should add `$set` operator, which is an atomic operator like $inc, $push etc., to make it an update query. Like this;

```
    var newvalues = { $set: {name: "Mickey", address: "Canyon 123"} };
```

Comment: the $set operator fixed the problem, i wonder why it was not specified on the w3school tutorial, thanks!

Comment: This worked for me. But I wonder why they made it necessary...

Answer (score 6):

The updateOne() method has the following form.

```
db.collection.updateOne(
   <filter>,
   <update>,
   {
     upsert: <boolean>,
     writeConcern: <document>,
     collation: <document>,
     arrayFilters: [ <filterdocument1>, ... ]
   }
)
```

**Example**

```
try {
   db.restaurant.updateOne(
      { "name" : "Pizza Rat's Pizzaria" },
      { $set: {"_id" : 4, "violations" : 7, "borough" : "Manhattan" } },
      { upsert: true }
   );
} catch (e) {
   print(e);
}
```